# How to encode a string into UTF-8 in JAVA

Tags: java, character-encoding

I have a Japanese String **文字列** I want to convert it to UTF-8 encoding. This question seems like a bit duplicate. I have googled for sometime but not able to find direct answer.

Comment: Just write it in the code in quotes, it will already be UTF8-encoded.

Comment: Please read [ask], then show us what you've tried and tell us the outcome, and where your problem is

Comment: @DmitryGinzburg: What makes you think that? And are you talking about in the source code (which could be in any encoding) or in the VM (which will typically use UTF-16)?

Comment: @JonSkeet I mean the source code.

Comment: @Dmitry: Why would you assume that a) the string is in source code, and b) the source code is in UTF-8? It's not clear how the source code encoding helps the OP anyway.

Answer (score 2):

Encoding a String is the process of transforming a sequence of characters into a sequence of bytes.

For that use the `getBytes()` method.

This method accepts and encoding parameter, which defines the encoding used in this process. Therefore, you can use :

```
byte[] encoded = "文字列".getBytes("UTF-8");
```

As per Jon Skeet comment, don't use magic strings:

```
byte[] encoded = "文字列".getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
```

Comment: Or better, in terms of not using magic strings... `getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8)`

Comment: @JonSkeet: I can't believe I never knew `StandardCharsets` existed.

Comment: @JonSkeet: Does that means that the Charsets referenced there are guaranteed to be supported?

Comment: As the [documentation says](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/charset/StandardCharsets.html), "These charsets are guaranteed to be available on every implementation of the Java platform."

Comment: @DavidConrad: My question comes from the fact that the documentation for that class on the Android platform says only: `Convenient access to the most important built-in charsets.`

Comment: Ooh, that would probably make a good question. I would certainly *hope* those are always present on Android, but I don't have any idea if they are.